# How to get content url in views-view-unformatted block template

Tags: 8, views, theming

In Drupal 8, I created template for solr search view **views-view-unformatted--solr_search_content--block.html.twig**

I am trying to print the content link by `{{ row.content['#view'].style_plugin.render_tokens[ loop.index0 ]['{{ title }}'] }}`

But displayed title with link. I need link only, Any Idea!

```
{% for row in rows %}
<div class="row block p-5">      
    <div class="views-row">
      {{- row.content -}}
    </div>      
    <div class="col-2 text-center chevron-right my-auto">
      <a href="{{ row.content['#view'].style_plugin.render_tokens[ loop.index0 ]['{{ title }}'] }}">
      <i class="fal fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you add a content url field to your view's fields in the UI and then render that?